# Movie about a man in Germany who is in legal trouble

Tags: identify-this-movie

I want to find a movie I partially and uninterestedly watched some years ago. For some reason I've been thinking compulsively about it in the last few months and want to see it again. The details in my memory about it are very scarce and probably inaccurate since I watched the movie with a lot of disdain; however I'll give it a try to see if any of you can identify it. So the things that I (very vaguely) remember are:

1. The location of the movie is, with almost all certainty, Germany.
2. The movie revolves around a young male who is in legal trouble in the country. For some reason I remember him as an illegal immigrant, but he could be a criminal or something who is being looked for by the authorities.
3. The guy has dark hair, and I would go with black hair specifically.
4. The guy falls in love with a woman native to the country.
5. Said woman has blonde hair.
6. In one scene, the guy is in the metro when two undercover police agents approach him, identify themselves as such, and ask him for his papers (ID or passport, I guess). The guy acts as if he's reaching for his wallet and as soon as the train stops in the next station he shoves them away and escapes.
7. The guy's love interest has an ex-husband, and one day he (our guy) shows to her place unannounced and finds them having sex. In anger, he punches her ex and the guy (the ex) leaves. When our guy confronts her, she justifies herself saying that her ex was helping her find jobs (she works as a photographer or something like that, I think).
8. In the last scene I can remember, the guy and the girl are sleeping together at her place until someone knocks on the door. When they open they find some policemen looking for the guy (I think they are the same agents he escaped from in the metro but I'm not sure). He tries to fool them and attempts an escape, but is ultimately captured.
9. For some reason I identify the guy as Russian, but there is nothing in my memories that justifies this.
10. The movie, as I remember it, didn't seem to be of the big-budget type and I don't remember any of the actors or actresses in the movie; had never seen them before, have never seen them again.

So there you go, that's all I can remember. Please take into account that my memories are very vague and cloudy, so probably the real scenes and characters in the movie don't match word by word to what I wrote above. So if you think you have seen some movie which resembles in any way to it, please leave the title in the comments; I would like to check it out.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like for the most part [A Most wanted Man.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1972571/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_4) This stars a (blonde) Rachel McAdams and Grigoriy Dobrygin who in this movie has dark hair. It's also the late PSH's last role released before he passed I believe. A political spy thriller.

The protagonist flees Russia or Chechnya after some kind of abuse/torture (he has some kind of wanted knowledge of the inner workings of terrorist organization's) and ends up illegally in Hamburg. I don't remember the love making scene as clear as you do, I remember him evading authorities as he arrives. He does end up falling in love with the blonde McAdams and she him as she becomes his lawyer and they spend time together. He ends up staying at her apartment.

While this guy is trying to get himself sorted in the back ground are at least two different intelligence agencies both trying to get a hold of him and make him their "property". A great spy thriller/drama really. At the end after some desperation and much frustration his is ultimately caught much to the chagrin of PSH who was doing his best for the MC.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I watched a couple of trailers of the movie and there are a couple of things that make me think this is not the movie I am looking for. 1. This movie was released almost two years ago; my memories of the movie are not that recent. 2. For what I can see this movie has some A-list stars. The movie I remember didn't (at least that I knew). 3. The movie I remember was not a thriller; it looked more like a drama movie. 4. The sex scene and the escape scene in the metro are probably the most clear memories I have of the movie. However I'll watch your movie and let you know.

Answer (score 3):

Well I've found the film, which in fact is a short film. It is called "[Fliegen](http://www.fliegen-film.de/Home.html)", was released in 2009 and is from Germany. For what I've been able to find out, things match pretty much to what I had in my memory. In fact the synopsis reads like this:

> Dima, a young petty criminal, is about to be deported from Germany
> when he meets a young student, Sarah, who is working on a documentary
> film about the lack of opportunities available to young foreigners.
>
> She offers him sanctuary in her garret – just for the sake of the film
> of course.
>
> Becoming aware of the attraction between them, Dima plays more than a
> role in Sarah’s documentary and they gradually leave the ground
> beneath their feet and learn, step by step, to fly.

The only problem is that it is almost impossible to get it online (and yes, I mean **legally**). If anybody knows of a way to watch this movie please let me know; I very much want to watch it.

Comment: You should mark your own answer as correct.